# How can I safely work around power lines?

Tags: electrical, painting, safety, exterior

I have to do some painting and repair work on the outside of the house near the incoming power line. The repair is pulling off molding and replacing it as well as painting the surrounding area.

I am going to get a fiberglass ladder to work around the area but is that enough? I will be so close that I am bound to touch it and it scares the crap out of me.

What else should I do to get this work done and still be alive to enjoy it after?

Comment: In my area the power company will do a disconnect/reconnect at no charge. They'd rather cover the cost than see your smoldering corpse in the newspapers.

Answer (score 11):

Call your utility company and have the power shut off at the pole for the duration of your work in that area.

Comment: Fair warning, this will probably cost you a fee.

Comment: In theory, properly installed power lines (residential service level) are insulated and, if undisturbed, should pose no serious risk. HOWEVER, accidents (and equipment failure) happen all the time and a stray tool can cut or damage insulation. The Evil One has a point.

Comment: The key word is "undisturbed".  If he's doing repair work right around the lines, the risk is them becoming disturbed.

Comment: I should note: the line is fairly new (<5 years) as a tree pulled it down and off the house just before we moved in. I will add to my question as it seems relevant. @TheEvilGreebo - The cut off is right across the street from me and when they have cut the power, it is for the entire street. Can they cut the power to just my house? Or is this going to affect everyone on the circuit?

Comment: @CarlB:  They won't use the switch.  They'll cut the wires going to your house and splice them back together at reconnect time.

Comment: Keep in mind that very often, the power company can turn off your service electronically with the tap of a few keys.  I have had that done with rural service delivered to a pole: I called thinking "it's 4:30, they'll never get anyone out" and I call anyway, they transfer me to "the right girl" and tappity tap, "give it a few minutes for the message to transmit, should be off then."  Apparently they use power line signaling and it's a lot like submarine comm ELF, has a very low baudrate.

Comment: @Harper - Was this shut off and turn on at the meter(Smart Meter)? If so, that would do me no good as these are the Mains going into the meter.

Comment: It really depends on their setup. In many cases, they can also remote the switches at their poletop, which may be viable if you're the only customer.  However after Ukraine they are now rethinking whether that is such a good idea.

Comment: In my area the pull the fuses on the pole so there is no power to the meter. Believe it or not many older homes the insulation is full of cracks and touching with a sweaty hand can provide a wake up and then possibly a fall.

Answer (score 5):

I've worked around power lines for years as well as other people in this thread. I always plan my work around the power company disconnecting. They are mostly accommodating with scheduling and I have never been charged. If they did charge, I would completely be ok with it. Better safe than sorry. I'm not in a hurry when I'm trying to do a job safe and right the first time.

Also, Someone mentioned that planning to fall off a ladder was not DIY advice. I beg to differ. If you don't plan on the what if's, you'll not know what to do if you do by chance fall. If I ever plan on doing serious work on a ladder, I usually open windows close to the work area, and if their aren't any windows, I have D rings and a harness. caulk the holes after your done.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I just talked to someone in the Austin, Texas Electric Distribution Department (Austin Utilities) and asked him about this. I am about to paint my house and I wanted to know if the utility company would turn off the power at the pole and what it would cost. He was a bit surprised at the question and said that people usually just paint around the weatherhead taking care, of course. He said that his workers just throw a rubber mat over the connections just to make sure. He suggested that I inspect the insulation first and if it's cracked, to call back and they will address that.

Answer (score 2):

In my area hydro (aka the electric utility) will come out for free and a rubber "boot/sock" around the stack to the house; this is extra insulation around the wires, making it safe to work around. So, the electricity is able to stay on while work is being done! They sometimes take 2-3 days to come out, so plan ahead.

Answer (score 1):

I grew up with the commercials that no line is safe to touch. So now I have to go up the front of my house where the power lines are I,ll be working off an aluminum ladder with the power lines directly behind my back, and if anyone thinks I'm not going to already have cmp wrap the lines I,m working around especially with a aluminum ladder,then your completely off your rocker anyone that gives u advise like go up and inspect the lines and if they look ok then go ahead and do what u have to do is just plain crazy and if anyone actually takes that advise then there crazier than the one that gave the advice. Always check with your power company before u do anything around but power lines. My idea if good advice is never carry our ladder straight up in case if power lines. My opinion

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Don't let anything touch those power lines. If you're not completely comfortable being on a ladder or just don't feel this is your forte, then call someone who is. Life is too full of risks as it is...

Answer (score -2):

> Edit:  As expected, some people don't like my answer.  I have decades of electrical and electronic experience and I suspect those who don't like my advice do not have a solid education/experience in basic electrical theory and practice.  However, I assure you that the wires are not as dangerous as popular ignorance imagines.

Climb up and have a close look at the wires you will be near.  If the utility is on the ball, they will be completely wrapped in insulation with no exposed metal—except for the neutral—and the connections (between the utility wires and the leads to the meter socket) wrapped in electrical tape.

If the wires are old, possibly there is some cracked insulation, maybe even seriously cracked enough for some bits of conductor to be exposed.  If cracking is serious or there is substantial cracking, call the utility and have them upgrade or wrap the wires.  They should do this for free.

If the wires are in good repair, you can safely work alongside them, even while touching them.  Respect them and keep all forms of metal away from them:  no metal hammer parts, paint roller, crowbars, putty knives, wedding rings, wristwatch, etc.  Use your fear of them to keep their position firmly in mind at all times.

If after working close to them and you still can't see yourself getting any closer, then by all means, call the utility and have them de-energized.  This may require a permit and inspection, so it may be days before power can be reconnected.  (I know permits and inspections don't make any sense, but the administrating authority is "just ensuring safety"—and making a living.)

If you were to fall off the ladder and the wires provided an opportunity to grab to save yourself, I would risk doing so.  Probably the arresting force will bend the weather head, and might pull apart the electrical connection.  After safely landing, keep the bare ends away from everything, and wrap them with electrical tape once you are steady on your feet.

Comment: Wow. I was with you (in theory; I would avoid this project, but that is a personal choice) until the last paragraph. If you meant to show just how low a risk it was, I think that goes a bit far. Planning on *how* to fall off a ladder is not my idea of DIY advice. (Not voting down because there are enough flags on the risks of this venture).

Comment: @bib:  Well, I wouldn't plan to grab onto the powerlines and do acrobatics, but if it was a choice of falling 1.5 stories or more and splatting on the sidewalk, grabbing the powerline is far more preferable.  The fall (well, the "hard landing") is very likely to result in substantial injuries; the powerline, probably not.

Comment: The service conductors are potentially unfused, which means there may be nothing to stop the flow of electricity. Inside your home a breaker/fuse (or GFCI) could trip and save your life. Outside the home, you could potentially be fried until the transformer blows.  Make a phone call, and have the service disconnected.

Comment: Decades of DIY electrical work, does not equal decades of electrical experience. Doing it wrong for a decade, does not mean you know how to do it right.

Comment: @Tester101:  I also have tangential electric utility experience.  My current project is for a major utility where I frequently converse with linemen, distribution engineers, and others.  Pole transformers have fuses, though I wouldn't want to perform an uncontrolled test of that.

Comment: @wallyk In your area they have fuses.  Remember this is an international site, so your advice reaches far beyond your city. I have no idea how much experience you actually have, but I would expect somebody with decades of experience to have a bit more respect for safety.

Comment: I am also adding the -1 vote due to the paragraph regarding the idea to grab the power lines in case of a fall from the ladder. If the usage area of the ladder is particularly dangerous (height, uneven ground, unstable ladder contact with building or far reach zone during work task) then separate and smart precautions should be taken. This may entail the use of a safety harness and safety rope over the building structure. It could also be a demand for using stacking scaffolding brackets and planks to establish a secure work site in the work area.